# Change src of img tag without knowing id or src of replacement

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've found some similar questions but never exactly this one:

I want to change the src of my img tag

```
<div id="probe1pic"><img height="193" width="150" src=""/></div>
```

and I want to do so with my jquery code from my variable x

```
x = {word: "David", pic: "<img id='pic' src='images/stimuli/david.gif'/>", type: "probe", cat: "perp"}
```

and if I isolate the pic element  with `x.pic` I get:

```
<img id='pic' src='images/stimuli/david.gif'/>
```

I thought about this to get the src element (unsuccessful):

```
x.pic.attr('src')
```

I probably need the id for of the img tag I want to get the attribute from which I do not know beforehand. I do not know the id nor the src beforehand, only my variable x with these elements, so I need to find a way to extract the src element from x (or the id at least).

Any ideas?

Comment: I guess x.pic.attr('src') because its a json object and you do not have a dom object to get with the help of attr. SO try to get the DOM and try gettign the attr

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`x.pic.src`

`$(x.pic).attr('src')`